# Flex error:2025 in migrating to Flex 3 to 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

Currently, I am doing a code migration from Flex 3 to 4 and I am setting currentState in initialize function of a popup.

code is like this,

```
 currentState = "xyz";

 // Now I try to access child which I am adding in "xyz" state definition.
 var childIndex:int = form.getChildIndex(childId); // this throws error 2025
```

State definition

```
<mx:State name="xyz">
    <!-- I remove some children and add some children before this -->   
   <mx:AddChild relativeTo="{form}" position="lastChild"
                creationPolicy="all">
    <mx:FormItem id="childId"
          label="Frequency">
        <mx:ComboBox id="cmbId"
                             dataProvider="{dataP}"
                 selectedIndex="0"
                             change="function()"/>                                     </mx:FormItem>
</mx:AddChild>
```

This piece of code was working fine until I started compiling code with flex 4.5sdk. Since then, it throws me Error#2025.

Any pointers?

Comment: Can you add the source code that has `id="form"`?  Can you confirm that the value of `childId` is an index that `form` has?

Comment: @ Mrk : I am adding a formItem with id="childId" in <mx:state "xyz" />

Comment: Code updated. Can anyone suggest what's wrong in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried to getChileIndex for childId in creationComplete method, it worked well. It seems that in initialize phase, we are trying to access a child index of the state and hence we get the error as that child might not have been laid out in the state.

Comment: But again, this specific issue came up when I compiled code using flex 4.5 sdk, it was working without any error when compiled with flex 3 sdk. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out what `.parent` is for `childId` prior to calling `form.childIndex(childId)`.  A #2025 error should be telling you that childId's parent is not `form` at the time you are calling `form.getChildIndex(childId)`

Try adding `trace("parent of childId " + childId.parent)` before the getChildIndex call:

```
trace("parent of childId " + childId.parent); 
form.childIndex(childId);
```

Or else, update your answer again and include the MXML for `form` that shows that childId is a direct descendent?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Mrk, I got a work around for this issue. I invested 2 days in that and to my surprise, when I tried to getChileIndex for childId in creationComplete method, it worked well. It seems that in initialize phase, it is not working. The interesting part is only that my current code is compiled by flex 4.5sdk and I got this issue whereas it was working great with flex 3 sdk.                                                                        I will try the suggestion tomorrow anyhow, thanks much...

Comment: When I traced for "childId.parent", it returned null.